# lower function in oracle 11g xe

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can i display 'mahesh' as first_name (col_name) from table where there are 5 records of same name 'mahesh','Mahesh', 'MAHESH', 'mAhESH', 'mahESH' and i want to display all the records?

```sql
select lower ('mahesh') from table_name;
```

and

```sql
select first_name, lower(first_name) 
from table_name 
where first_name='mahesh';
```

desired result must be that all records of name mahesh must be displayed.

Comment: Change where clause in your last attempt to `where lower(first_name)='mahesh'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select lower(first_name) from table_name where lower(first_name) = 'mahesh';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Order by first_name desc see samole

```
select first_name from myname where lower(first_name) = 'mahesh'
  ORDER BY first_name DESC;
```

| FIRST_NAME |
| --- |
| mahesh |
| mahESH |
| mAhESH |
| Mahesh |
| MAHESH |

```
select first_name from myname where lower(first_name) = 'mahesh'
ORDER BY NLSSORT(first_name, 'NLS_SORT = BINARY') DESC
```

| FIRST_NAME |
| --- |
| mahesh |
| mahESH |
| mAhESH |
| Mahesh |
| MAHESH |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6fy1W1x-)